# Ruby, openGL : change texture luminosity

Tags: ruby, opengl, textures

I have some problems with OpenGL and luminosity. Let me explain you my problem :

[image: sprite]

I drew this "sprite" (it's only a plane here) with a code like that :

```
sprite.set_active
left, right, top, bottom = 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0
glPushMatrix
    glTranslate(@position.x - 16, @position.y, @position.z)
    glRotate(-90 -@window.camera.horizontal_angle, 0, 1, 0)
    glScale(chara.width, chara.height, 32.0)
    begin
        glEnable(GL_BLEND)
        glBegin(GL_QUADS)
            glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
            glTexCoord2d(left, top); glVertex3f(0, 1, 0.5)
            glTexCoord2d(right, top); glVertex3f(1, 1, 0.5)
            glTexCoord2d(right, bottom); glVertex3f(1, 0, 0.5)
            glTexCoord2d(left, bottom); glVertex3f(0, 0, 0.5)
        glEnd
        glDisable(GL_BLEND)
    rescue

    end
glPopMatrix
```

My problem is with that line :

```
glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
```

Well, I can put a number lesser than 1.0 to have a darker sprite, but I can't do the contrary. How can I do that ? How can I make the sprite be totally white, for example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get full control over your fragment processing, the best approach is using the programmable pipeline, where you can implement exactly what you want with GLSL code.

But there are some options that could work for this case in the fixed pipeline. The simplest one is using a different `GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE`. The default value is `GL_MODULATE`, which means that the color you specified with `glColor4f()` is multiplied with the color from the texture. As you found, that allows you to make the texture darker, but not brighter.

You could try using `GL_ADD` instead. As the name suggests, this will produce the final output as the sum of the texture color and the color from `glColor4f()`. For example:

```
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_ADD);
glColor4f(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.0f);
```

would add 0.2 to the color components read from the texture.

There is more complex functionality in the fixed pipeline that gives you more control over how texture values are used to generate colors. You can find it by looking for "texture combiners". But in my personal opinion, you're much better off moving to the programmable pipeline if you need something complex enough to require texture combiners.

Comment: Thanks god it's finally working ! Do you know how to manage saturation too with that kind of solution ?